# Intercept JSON prior to RestKit

Tags: json, restkit

The company I'm working at is considering using RestKit.  However, the JSON that our server returns is surrounded characters for security reasons.  It's a pain.  In another iPhone app, one that does not use RestKit and uses JSON only very little, I parse the string returned from the server, removing the characters preceding and trailing the JSON string.  Once the the string is parsed, I call JSONValue on the string (we're using SBJSON) and get an NSDictionary.

I've heard that RestKit features a pluggable architecture.  If that's the case is there somewhere I can intercept the strings coming back from the server prior to the point where RestKit does its parsing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wanted to find a fix that did not require me to change the RestKit codebase in any way and I found it. The answer was to create and register my own parser.

Parsers need to conform to the RKParser protocol.  Basically what I needed to do was trim the server response and not parse the response into objects - there was already a parser that did that: RKJSONParserJSONKit. So I subclassed this class and registered my parser at start up:

```
[[RKParserRegistry sharedRegistry] setParserClass:[MyJSONParser class] 
                                      forMIMEType:@"application/json"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to note that nowadays you can implement your own retrieve/map operation by subclassing the

- `RKHTTPRequestOperation` [(doc)](http://restkit.org/api/0.20.3/Classes/RKHTTPRequestOperation.html) — for retrieving file from server
- `RKObjectRequestOperation` [(doc)](http://restkit.org/api/0.20.3/Classes/RKObjectRequestOperation.html) — for mapping
- `RKManagedObjectRequestOperation`  [(doc)](http://restkit.org/api/0.20.3/Classes/RKManagedObjectRequestOperation.html) — for mapping to core data objects

and registering them with `[RKObjectManager registerRequestOperationClass:]` [(doc)](http://restkit.org/api/0.20.3/Classes/RKObjectManager.html#//api/name/registerRequestOperationClass:) method.